# prove that test statistic follows normal distribution

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

We consider a test statistic $Z = \frac{| \bar{X} - \bar{Y} |}{\sigma} \sqrt{\frac{n}{2}}$, where

$$\bar{X} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$$

$$\bar{Y} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nY_i$$

$$X_i \sim N(\mu_1 , \sigma^2)$$

$$Y_i \sim N(\mu_2 , \sigma^2)$$

We're testing a zero hypothesis that $\mu_1 = \mu_2$ against the alternative that $\mu_1 \neq \mu_2$. I need to find Z's distribution, and since it's supposed to be a z-test, I expect it to be normal.

So, the way I see it, by CLT Z will follow normal distribution N(0,1) for big enough $n$ under zero hypothesis - but I'm not sure that it's actually the answer, since I think it should work for all values of $n$. The cause of my confusion is the absolute value - if we add or substract normal variables, the distribution will stay normal, only changing parameters. However absolute value of a normal variable doesn't have to be normal, and in fact I'm pretty sure that usually isn't.

I see 3 options here:

1) There's something really basic here that I just don't understand.
2) The CLT argument is actually enough explanation and it's supposed to only work for big samples.
3) The assumption of normality of Z is just wrong.

I expect that similar questions happened multiple times already, but for reasons unknown I couldn't find any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The central limit theorem does not bear upon this, because the random variables you're starting with are already normally distributed. A linear combination of independent normally distributed random variables, in which the coefficients are not random variables but constants, is normally distributed. (You didn't mention independence, but I surmise that you intended that, and should have mentioned it.)

The central limit theorem treats of independent identically distributed random variables with finite variance that are *not* assumed to be normally distributed.

Comment: As I mentioned in the post, I'm aware of the fact that linear combination of normally distributed variables would be normally distributed; however in the test statistic we also take the absolute value of them and that's not a linear operation, which is the cause of my confusion.

Comment: @Salieri : The absolute value of a normally distributed random variable cannot be normally distributed since it cannot be negative. The idea is that you reject this null hypothesis if a certain normally distributed random variable is either too big or too small, and that's the same as saying its absolute value is too big.

Comment: Well then the answer to whether Z is normally distributed is actually "no", right? What's really happening here is we're calculating the statistic Z without | | which is normally distributed and check for -t < Z < t, but using absolute value in the equation allows us to reduce it equivalently to |Z| < t?

Comment: @Salieri : Correct. $\qquad$